# Integrate ui with web3 for transfer funds from safe wallet to receipent

Tags: gnosis-safe

```js
const Web3 = require('web3')

const provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(
  'wss://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/API_KEY',
)
const web3 = new Web3(provider)

const txHash =
  'TxHash'

// Replace with the actual ABI and address of the Gnosis Safe contract
const safeAddress = 'SafeAddr'
const safeAbi =[]

const safeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(safeAbi, safeAddress)
const recipient = 'recipientAddr'
const transferFunds = async () => {
  try {
    const txData = safeContract.methods
      .execTransaction(
        recipient,
        web3.utils.toWei('0.001', 'ether'), // Transfer amount (0.1 ETH)
        '0x', // transaction data (if any)
        0, // Enum.Operation.Call or Enum.Operation.DelegateCall
        2000000, // safeTxGas
        0, // baseGas
        web3.utils.toWei('30', 'gwei'),
        'GasAddress', // address of delegate (if operation is DELEGATECALL)
        'ReceipentAddr',
        '0x2',
      )
      .encodeABI()

    // Estimate gas required for the transaction
    const estimatedGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
      to: safeAddress,
      data: txData,
      nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(
        'Fromaddr',
      ), // Get the correct nonce value
    })

    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
      {
        to: safeAddress,
        data: txData,
        gas: estimatedGas + 100000, // Increase the gas limit by a reasonable amount
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(3), // Replace with the correct nonce
      },
      'PrivateKey', // Private key of one of the Safe owners
    )

    const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(
      signedTx.rawTransaction,
    )
    console.log(txReceipt)

  
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

transferFunds()
```

For that calling execTransaction function, getting error execution reverted: GS020.

How should i resolved it any solutions.??